# Is "using namespace" transitive in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

To my astonishment the following code compiles and prints "X" on VC++ 2017:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


namespace A {
    using namespace std;
}

namespace B {
    using namespace A;
}

namespace C {
    using namespace B;
    string a;
}

int main()
{
    C::a = "X";
    std::cout << C::a;
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like the `using namespace std` works from namespace A through namespace B into namespace C.

Is this a bug in Visual C++ or does it concur with the language specification?

I had expected that `using namespace std` ends at the end of the enclosing scope which is at the end of the definition of namespace A.

EDIT: I understand that the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775563/using-namespace-statement-inside-an-anonymous-namespace?noredirect=1&lq=1) also answers my question. But that post is more about anonymous namespaces, while this one is about the transitivity of the using namespace directive. So I think it s a better example and the question makes sense.

Comment: @LogicStuff: My question is similar but not the same. It has nothing to do with anonymous namespaces and others that search for the problem won't find that answer like I did not.

Comment: Why souldn't it work exactly? `using namespace` imports all names into the host namespace, they don't vanish afterwards.

Comment: @KitFisto It is a subquestion of the linked question, answered in the first sentence of the accepted answer. What is the problem?

Comment: @LogicStuff: It is true that one of the answers to that other question also answers my question. But the questions themselves are different as far as I see it.

Comment: @KitFisto: Despite the name, "duplicate" is often used when the answers match, as long as the question is on sufficiently the same topic. It's a balancing act but there is no point in repeating answers just because the question differs slightly. Read "here's a duplicate" as "your answer may be found here". That all being said, I would _not_ consider these questions to be sufficiently similar for that to be a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

> `[C++14: 7.3.4/4]:` For unqualified lookup (3.4.1), **the *using-directive* is transitive**: if a scope contains a *using-directive* that nominates a second namespace that itself contains *using-directives*, the effect is as if the using-directives from the second namespace also appeared in the first. *[..]*

So, the compiler is correct; `using namespace` here effectively imports the names into the enclosing namespace:

> `[C++14: 7.3.4/2]:` A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. *[..]*

The "scope" here is that of the namespace; the contents of a scope doesn't vanish just because a `}` is encountered. Familiarity with block scopes sometimes makes it feel that way, though.